# How does dual wielding affect my damage output as a demon hunter?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When dual wielding weapons, how is damage calculated for skills that do X% weapon damage?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/31226/when-dual-wielding-weapons-how-is-damage-calculated-for-skills-that-do-x-weapo)

I tried out demon hunter after getting a nice 1-hand weapon for the class, when I got the Demon hunter to the level needed to equip it I moved my starting weapon to my offhand hoping this would give me higher damage, but the result was not very impressive when using Hungering Arrow, about half my shots was a nice high damage and the other half was low, like if the ability used the different weapons to calculate damage so I dropped my starting weapon for a shield. So to get a better understanding of why my damage was so terrible when dual wielding a good and a bad weapon I would like to know:

**How is my damage done by skill calculated when dual wielding 1-hand crossbows compared to when using a 1-hand crossbow and shield or a 2-hand range weapon?**