# How do attacks per second work while dual wielding?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is listed DPS calculated when dual-wielding weapons?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30982/how-is-listed-dps-calculated-when-dual-wielding-weapons)

If I equip a dagger in my mainhand (1.31 APS) and then an axe in my offhand (1.30 APS) my attacks per second go up to 1.51. Makes sense based on [this](http://www.osirisguide.com/diablo-3-dual-wield-guide/) guide.

However, when I unequip both weapons, then equip the axe in my offhand first, then the dagger in my mainhand, my attacks per second *drops* to 1.28.

**These are the same weapons equipped in the same slots, just in a different order.**

The same thing happens if I switch it up and do Axe mainhand, Dagger offhand.

Why the difference?

EDIT: I have noticed that the net damage on the main inventory window does not change. Just the attack speed in the expanded details window.

Comment: Ahh, I see the good old lying character screen (LCS) is back from D2!

Comment: Why was this closed? It isn't a duplicate at all. The other question mentions nothing about why the order weapons are equipped affects attack speed. Even if this ends up being just a display bug, it's a different question.

Comment: I found the answer to this question: It's because you alternate attacks while dual wielding, and each attack uses its own attack speed. Equipping weapons in a different order is just changing which weapon you attack with first, which explains the behavior above.