# Explanation for Attack speed with dual items in Diablo 3

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is listed DPS calculated when dual-wielding weapons?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30982/how-is-listed-dps-calculated-when-dual-wielding-weapons)

I've read somewhere in-game ( i don't remember where exactly though) that when dual-wielding, attack speed differs when you're using incompatible items or something?

So does it matter if I equip a one-handed spear and a fist vs 2 spears and 2 fists? Also, do they need to have the same attack speed?

Comment: This is a dupe, if someone better at searching wants to cast the first vote.

Comment: sorry if that is the case, feel free to close and link to the other one. I tried to look for the answer here first but I also couldn't find it

Comment: no worries, I'd do it myself, but searching via mobile is even worse than searching in general. I'm sure someone will come along and find it once they know to look. :)