# Calculating Dual Wield Character DPS

Tags: diablo-iii

I've been hacking through several formulas across this site and others. I'm running into problems trying to figure out the true DPS when the character is dual wielding. Let's take a low level Barbarian for example.

```
Strength: 28
Damage Increased by Skills: 0%
Attacks per second: 1.24
Crit Chance: 5%
Crit Hit Damage: 50%

Weapon Stats:
1 Hand Spear: 7-11 Damage
Spear Base Attacks per Second: 1.20
Bonus: Increase Attack Speed by 3%
```

So, the formula for this would be (or any one handed character):

```
7 + 11 = **18**; (weapon damage range added together)
1.20 * (1 + (3 * 0.01)) = **1.236**; (base weapon speed, times any IAS bonus on the weapon plus 1)
(0 * 0.01) + 1 = **1**; (damage bonus from skills. this character has 0)
((5 * 0.01) * (50 * 0.01)) + 1 = **1.025**; (crit chance * crit damage)
(28 * 0.01) + 1 = **1.28**; (attribute to percent + 1)
```

multiple all of the results above, and divide by two and you get:
**14.59**

which is the correct DPS of the character. But now, how would you calculate the DPS of an offhand weapon equipped to this character, say:

```
1H Axe
Base Speed: 1.30
Damage Range: 9-14
```

Does anyone know how to calculate this?

Comment: There's [another question here with an explicit formula in its accepted answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30982/how-is-listed-dps-calculated-when-dual-wielding-weapons). Have you tried using it?

Comment: @Oak Yeah i see it. That formula calculates the weapon speed while dual wielding. I already have that covered.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the Damage stat on the character sheet actually mean? How is it Calculated?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67843/what-does-the-damage-stat-on-the-character-sheet-actually-mean-how-is-it-calcul)

Comment: @JackStanley Then you haven't read it closely enough, because it covers DPS while dual wielding. Use the average damage of *both weapons*, calculated together, account for the 15% speed increase, and you get the proper result.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz The math doesn't match the in game displayed result following any of that thread's advice. I'm guessing the  game has bugs.

Comment: @Jack What number is the game telling you?  My math says it should be 19.6

Comment: The number in game is for guidance only anyway, I managed to bug my demon hunter's DPS from 78k to 1.1k earlier by unequipping my bow and putting it back on again.

Answer (score 3):

The actual formula the game calculates damage is:

> (AvgMainHandHit + AvgOffHandHit) / (MainHandSwingTime + OffHandSwingTime)

which equals:

> ( Average Double Hit Damage ) / ( Average Double Hit Time ).

I purposefully named it Hands, because we calculate both weapon and character statistics into it.

Answer (score 2):

The formula for damage is:

(1 + passive skill boosts)*(Average Weapon Damage + ((minimum damage bonus + maximum damage bonus)/2))*(Weapon Damage Multipliers)*(Attack Speed)*(1 + ( crit% * crit damage %))*( 1 + (main stat / 100))

For Dual Wielding:

((1 + passive skill boosts)*(Weapon 1 average damage + ((minimum damage bonus + maximum damage bonus)/2))*(Weapon Damage Multipliers)*(Attack Spee)*(1 + ( crit% * crit damage %))*( 1 + (main stat / 100))*(average attack speed of both weapons / weapon 1 attack speed) + (1 + passive skill boosts)*(Weapon 2 average damage + ((minimum damage bonus + maximum damage bonus)/2))*(Weapon Damage Multipliers)*(Attack Speed)*(1 + ( crit% * crit damage %))*( 1 + (main stat / 100))*(average attack speed of both weapons / weapon 2 attack speed)) * 0.575

Comment: This is why Gaming needs embedded LaTeX :(

Comment: what is the "Weapon Damage Multipliers"?