# Why does replacing my offhand crossbow with a quiver increase my damage? (screenshot)

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is listed DPS calculated when dual-wielding weapons?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30982/how-is-listed-dps-calculated-when-dual-wielding-weapons)

Below is a screenshot of what I'm referring to. How does a Quiver with those stats increase my total damage when it replaces a one handed crossbow (in my offhand) that has 292.6 damage?

I know the damage calculation in D3 is somewhat complicated, but this doesn't make sense to me at all.

[image: Quiver vs. Bow]

Comment: According to [the answer here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/30999/16953), my guess is your primary weapon is much more powerful than the off-hand weapon you're replacing with a quiver.  So you're losing out on damage by dual-weilding, since it makes you alternate shots between the two weapons, and with imbalanced weapons you alternate between a powerful shot and a weak shot.

Comment: Also, the quiver is going to add a lot of attack speed to your primary weapon, further magnifying its DPS.

Comment: The only benefit of duel-wielding is the increased attack speed.  Since quivers also give you increased attack-speed, I don't see why you would ever duel-wield with a demon hunter.