# Dual wield damage calculation

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is listed DPS calculated when dual-wielding weapons?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30982/how-is-listed-dps-calculated-when-dual-wielding-weapons)

I've seen other similar posts on this, but still have some questions.  In this formula:

((1 + passive skill boosts)(Weapon 1 average damage + ((minimum damage bonus + maximum damage bonus)/2))(Weapon Damage Multipliers)(Attack Speed)(1 + ( crit% * crit damage %))( 1 + (main stat / 100))(average attack speed of both weapons / weapon 1 attack speed) + (1 + passive skill boosts)(Weapon 2 average damage + ((minimum damage bonus + maximum damage bonus)/2))(Weapon Damage Multipliers)(Attack Speed)(1 + ( crit% * crit damage %))( 1 + (main stat / 100))(average attack speed of both weapons / weapon 2 attack speed)) * 0.575

1. What are the "Weapon Damage Multipliers"?
2. Does the "Attack Speed" include the 15% bonus for dual wield?
3. Does the "average attack speed of both weapons" include the 15% bonus for dual wield?
4. Does "weapon 1 attack speed" include the 15% bonus for dual wield?

Comment: That seems needlessly complicated.  The weapon tooltip won't take the dual wield bonus into account, but the details screen should.  And that's easy to test.

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer 1. My best guess is the answer to all the other ones is "Yes".

The damage multiplier is the factor by which the value of your primary attribute (Strength for Barbarian, Dexterity for Demon Hunter and Monk, Intelligence for Witch Doctor and Wizard) influences your damage.

Comment: Main stat is already accounted for in the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Primary attribute should be ( 1 + (main stat / 100)) in the formula